# Are the MIT Introduction to C++ lecture notes any good?

Tags: c++

I've been wondering if [these lecture notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-096-introduction-to-c-january-iap-2011/lecture-notes/) from an *Introduction to C++* course are good material for me to learn the language.

Does this material contain any gross factual errors in it? Will I learn some concepts in a wrong way with them? Will I get any bad practices from it?

Comment: In my opinion Uni courses do not provide a very deep insight. You should better get one of the books here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list I personally recommend Accelerated C++

Comment: "be better of reading a tutorial ?" (sic) No. Online tutorials are among the worst possible ways to "learn" C++. Grab a book as from the list Muggen linked to.

Comment: @ildjarn etc: can you folks please stop closing questions that YOU cannot answer. or move somewhere else please.

Comment: @aman: the original MIT Open Courseware C++ course was unfortunately of **[very low quality, full of factual errors](http://goo.gl/MGlov)**. The next one, from the mid-term course a year later, was much improved. And judging from a cursory review of the first PDF you link to, the current stuff is **good**.

Comment: Those are transcribed notes.. and have errors yes. A book is good !

Comment: This is a really good tutorial from beginning till the end:http://pragsoft.com/cgi-bin/load.cgi?http://www.pragsoft.com/books/CppEssentials.pdf

Comment: You really shouldn't expect to download some random lecture notes and expect to get a comprehensive picture of anything. Lecture notes are supposed to augment the lecture, not replace it.

Answer (score 8):

The original MIT Open Courseware C++ course was unfortunately of [very low quality, full of factual errors](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/browse_frm/thread/d2ba04a6a7841f01/7021ce9c688dfcbd?tvc=1&q=mit+c%2B%2B+group:comp.programming&pli=1). The next one, from the mid-term course a year later, was much improved. And judging from a cursory review of the first PDF you link to, the current stuff is good.

However, as @Muggen remarked, you should better get one of the well known C++ books such as one of the books in the [Stack Overflow C++ book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), e.g. *Accelerated C++*.

A book is much more complete and dependable.